# Why my website lags when I scroll down - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, lag

Hi I got this website (no domain yet). And when u scroll on homepage It start lagging in google chrome. Can somebody tell me why? Thank you

http://325036.w36.wedos.ws/

There is a code for appearing image while scrolling:

```
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame || function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)}

var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".eventyPic, .eventyPic2, .eventyPic3, .categoryText, .absolutePhoto")

function loop() {
    elementsToShow.forEach(function (element) {
        if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
            element.classList.add("is-visible")
        } else {
            element.classList.remove("is-visible")
        }
    })
    scroll(loop)
}

loop()

function isElementInViewport(el) {
    // Special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    var topVisible = rect.top >= 0 && rect.top < windowHeight;
    var bottomVisible = rect.bottom > 0 && rect.bottom <= windowHeight;
    var leftVisible = rect.left >= 0 && rect.left < windowWidth;
    var rightVisible = rect.right > 0 && rect.right <= windowWidth;

    return (topVisible || bottomVisible) && (leftVisible || rightVisible);
}
```

I was trying to change code, but i dont know what to do next.

Comment: This approach is very old. Use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)